# Event handlers work in IE11 or Chrome, but not both

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6, internet-explorer-11

In a codebase I help maintain there exists a function of this form (stripped down for brevity):

```
function setListeners(enable) {
    const fn = enable ? document.body.addEventListener : document.body.removeEventListener;

    fn('click', foo);
    fn('MyCustomEvent', bar);
}
```

IE11 throws `Illegal Invocation`, while other browsers work fine. Another maintainer switched the function to this form:

```
function setListeners(enable) {
    const fn = enable ? document.body.addEventListener : document.body.removeEventListener;

    fn.call(document.body, 'click', foo);
    fn.call(document.body, 'MyCustomEvent', bar);
}
```

Now it works in IE11, but not Chrome. We already have a polyfill for CustomEvent (which has an implied use as shown), but what else is preventing this function from staying cross-browser?

Comment: You definitely need the `.call` approach, so what failed in Chrome?

Comment: Since the second version should work, the problem is probably elsewhere in your code. So you'll need to show more of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second code snippet should be fine. Here's a working example (tested successfully in Chrome for me):

```js
const fn = document.body.addEventListener;

fn.call(document.body, 'MyCustomEvent', e => {
  console.log('MyCustomEvent', e.detail);
});

document.body.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('MyCustomEvent', {
  detail: 'it worked!'
}));
```

Perhaps your `CustomEvent` polyfill is getting in the way, or there are other factors at play that aren't shown?

Comment: I can't paste proprietary code, so I'll accept this and move on with that info. Thank you!